# android is it possible to get all the dates from a year by entering a day of the week?

Tags: java, android, calendar

i want to do a timetable - that allows the user to sets a tasks that he will have. so let's say that on  monday the user sets that he is going to the gym - than i want to applay it to every monday on the next weeks.

So what i want to know is, as my title is says,  is it possible to get all the dates from a year by entering a day of the week? and if so how would i do it?
thanks for any kind of help

Comment: what does " is it possible to get all the dates from a year by entering a day of the week" mean?

Comment: It means - let's say the user saying he got something to do on mondays - something thast will repeat itself on every week - so i want to run over the year dates and get from it all dates that are falling on mondays and add the task for each one of those dates

Comment: You could repeatedly call the [`plusWeeks( 1 )`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusWeeks(int)) method on DateTime instance in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// init to date picked by user
cal.setTime(myDate);
while([your stop condition here]) {
    // go to same day next week
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date next = cal.getTime();
    // .. do something with the date
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you fro trying to help, but i don't undersdtand what should i enter ro Date next, what cal.add stands for? and whe shoul i need to enter to the cal.setTime?

Comment: I added comments, you should also read `Calendar` javadoc.